# Resources for morphological etymology research

Tags: etymology, american-english, british-english, morphology

I am attempting to write a short paper on English etymology focusing on Germanic, French, and Latin morphology. I need to present a means of identifying these roots by common morphologies in English, rather than lists of words. As an example, all I've been able to find is an unscholarly [article](https://www.thoughtco.com/how-french-has-influenced-english-1371255) that states "Whereas Old English had the unvoiced fricative sounds [f], [s], [θ] (as in thin), and [∫] (shin), French influence helped to distinguish their voiced counterparts [v], [z], [ð] (the), and [ʒ] (mirage), and also contributed the diphthong [ɔy] (boy)." I need to find more scholarly sources with more content of exactly this nature for all three root languages.

I'm surprised at the lack of such resources, and this project does not call or allow time for extensive research, so I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: What do you mean by "common morphologies in English"? The goal of your paper is not clear.

Comment: I mean to make a generalization - the English morphemes given as examples can, according to that article, be generalized as having French origin. I mean both morphemes that are "common" or have a relatively high use frequency in English, providing ready and broad applicability, as well as commonality with the root language. The latter is a bit more important to me than the former.

Comment: I could say that I'm looking for general means of identifying the linguistic roots of English words by morphological analysis, but it seems that the vast majority of available resources focus primarily on lists of loan-words.

Comment: That's because loan-words constitute about half the vocabulary of English. If one can learn to recognize English words borrowed from Greek, Latin, and French, and distinguish them from words that were originally English, one can distinguish formal from informal styles very easily, and translate back and forth. The borrowed words are more prestigious and appear in writing and formal discourse much more often.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. I understand that loan-words make up a significant portion of English. Therefore, Germanic, French, and Latin must have some distinct morphologies that can be used to identify their root presence in English words. I am seeking resources to construct a primer on English etymology based upon that principle.

Comment: Not so much morphologies as individual sounds. Grimm's Law is a big set of parallel consonants in Germanic (English) versus French, Latin, and Greek (and most other IE languages, too, but English didn't borrow much from Slavic or Iranian). Only the Germanic consonants changed, in predictable patterns, but the Latin and Greek consonants stayed pretty much the same. So you get _paternal_ but _father_, where Latin has [p] and [t] but English has [f] and [ð], by Grimm's Law. PIE p -> f and t -> þ in Germanic, and there's ten other changes parallel to these.